How to reuse the logic behind canActivate/canChildActivate for the same route's anchor elements?
Here are my routes:
export const routes: Routes =[
{
    path: '', component: DefaultLayoutComponent, canActivate: [AuthGuard], canActivateChild: [AuthGuard],
    children: [
      { path: 'dashboard', component: DashboardComponent },
      {
        path: 'admin-only', component: AdminOnlyComponent,
        data: { authorize: (c: any) => c.role == "Admin" }
      },
      {
        path: 'admin-or-teacher', component: AdminOrTeacherComponent,
        data: { authorize: (c: any) => c.role == "Admin" || c.role == "Teacher" }
      }
]

Inside the AuthGuard I execute the authorize method to decide whether to activate the route or not. which is working perfectly fine.
Now inside the dashboard components, I have following nav links.
<ul class="nav flex-column w-100 px-3">
    <li class="nav-item">
      <a class="nav-link" routerLink="/admin-only">Admin Only</a>
    </li>
    <li class="nav-item">
      <a class="nav-link" routerLink="/admin-or-teacher">Admin Or Teacher</a>
    </li>
</ul>

I want to re-use the same call back authorize to hide these links based on user claims. How to do it?

Please share the minimal reproducible code, issue you are facing, your question is just stating requirements, not asking to solve a problem in the code.

@NarenMurali what else you need? I'm not asking for bug fix, I looking for a solution.

@Shamsser require the code you tried to solve the problem
